# GAC appears to be broken on freshly installed Windows 10

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-10, gac, gacutil

After repeatedly getting `2147024891` errors while trying to install some 3rd party controls, investigation shows that it is unable to install some DLL's into the GAC. I tried to find out why, and here are a few other symptoms I ran into:

- Browsing to `C:\Windows\assembly` gives an empty list.
- From the Developer Command Prompt (as admin), `gacutil -l` returns `Number of items = 0`
- Using a DOS Command prompt to list the contents of `C:\Windows\assembly` and `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly` shows that there are quite some items installed.
- Nirsofts [GacViewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/dot_net_tools/gac_viewer.html) tool shows 589 installed assemblies.
- Visual studio is running, can open and build solutions, only the WinForms designer has [some quirks](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/448324/winforms-designer-controls-are-disabled-and-listed.html) (probably related to missing items in the GAC?).

It looks like a permissions issue at first glance, but I am local administrator on my machine, so what could be the problem? Does windows 10 require any additional rights for manipulating the GAC that a "local admin" does not have by default?

If I rightclick, and choose "run as administrator" to open a command prompt, and then run:

```
gacutil -i myassembly.dll
```

Then I still get:

> Failure adding assembly to the cache: Administrator permissions are needed to use the selected options. Use an administrator command prompt to complete these tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing the [Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30135), all the problems disappeared.

Apparently disabling the `Windows Search` service can help in some cases, but that didn't work for me. The repair tool did.